# .getImage() on a null object reference android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I have a fragment. After click on image i strart activity. But i keep getting this error

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.flag.app/com.flag.app.app.activity.MarkerDetailsActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.flag.app.app.model.Image com.flag.app.app.model.Marker.getImage()' 
on a null object reference
```

So, this is my activity

```
public class MarkerDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static Intent getStartIntent(Context context, Marker marker) {
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, MarkerDetailsActivity.class);
    startIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MARKER, marker);
    return startIntent;
}


ImageView mImageView;
TextView mNameTextView;
Marker mMarker;
MapView mMapView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_marker);
    mMarker = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_MARKER);

    mImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    mMapView = findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bindMarker(mMarker);
}

private void bindMarker(Marker marker) {
    Picasso.with(mImageView.getContext())
            .load(marker.getImage().getUrl())
            .into(mImageView);
    mAuthorTextView.setText(marker.getAuthor());
    mDescriptionTextView.setText(marker.getDescription());
    mDateTextView.setText(marker.getDate());

}
   }
```

How to fix it?

Comment: How do you know `getParcelableExtra` actually returned a value?

Comment: getParcelableExtra actually didn`t returned a value? How to fix it?

Comment: Is that a question or a verification? You need to show how you are using getStartIntent method

Answer (score 0):

Check for null value.

```
private void bindMarker(Marker marker) {
if(marker != null){
    Picasso.with(mImageView.getContext())
            .load(marker.getImage().getUrl())
            .into(mImageView);
    mAuthorTextView.setText(marker.getAuthor());
    mDescriptionTextView.setText(marker.getDescription());
    mDateTextView.setText(marker.getDate());

}}
```

Comment: The image of the marker could still be null

Answer (score 0):

```
private void bindMarker(Marker marker) {
    if(marker!=null){
        if(marker.getImage()!=null) {
            Picasso.with(mImageView.getContext())
                    .load(marker.getImage().getUrl())
                    .into(mImageView);
        }
        mAuthorTextView.setText(marker.getAuthor());
        mDescriptionTextView.setText(marker.getDescription());
        mDateTextView.setText(marker.getDate());
    }
}
```

you have to check before using `Marker` object is null or not